# mongodb = trigger => python

Tags: python, mongodb, triggers, real-time

I'm currently building a pipeline that reads data from MongoDB everytime new document gets inserted and send it to external data source after some preprocessing. Preprocessing and sending data to external data source part works well the way I designed.

The problem, however, I can't read data from MongoDB. I'm trying to build a trigger that reads data from MongoDB when certain MongoDB collection gets updated then sends it to python. I'm not considering polling a MongoDB since it's too resource-intensive.

I've found this library mongotriggers(https://github.com/drorasaf/mongotriggers/) and now taking a look at it.

---

In summary, how can I build a trigger that sends data to python from MongoDB when new document gets inserted to specific collection?

Any comment or feedback would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Best

Gee

Comment: Behold the [oplog](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/). Every such service writen basically listens for changes on this. No polling required.

Comment: Thx @NeilLunn oplog seems to be the right apporach!

Comment: @GeeYeolNahm I have a similar use case. Did you write working code using oplog? If you did, please consider to share the code (answer your own question). Thanks!

Comment: @Vingtoft Sorry for not leaving a comment. I ended up not using oplog. We just didn't anymore needed to proceed that work. If I get back to that work and have it solved using oplog, I'll definitely come back here and answer my own question.

Answer (score 3):

In MongoDB v3.6+, you can now use [MongoDB Change Streams](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/). Change streams allow applications to access real-time data changes without the complexity and risk of tailing the oplog. Applications can use change streams to subscribe to all data changes on a single collection, a database, or an entire deployment, and immediately react to them.

For example to listen to streams from MongoDB when a new document gets inserted:

```
try:
    with db.collection.watch([{'$match': {'operationType': 'insert'}}]) as stream:
        for insert_change in stream:
            # Do something
            print(insert_change)
except pymongo.errors.PyMongoError:
    # The ChangeStream encountered an unrecoverable error or the
    # resume attempt failed to recreate the cursor.
    logging.error('...')
```

[pymongo.collection.Collection.watch()](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.watch) is available from PyMongo 3.6.0+.

Comment: I opted to use MongoTriggers instead of Mongo's OPlog, because for the latter it is necessary to configure replicas

Comment: Domenico Monaco, if your trigger fails to communicate with whatever dependency it's communicating, will the event get retried?